# How to avoid some fields to be bound on form submit?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a simple form that edits my profile on the web. 'Person' bean, that describes user, contains many internal fields that cannot be changed by the form. Therefore I have just a subset of fields available for editing on the form. So far so good. Now what if some advanced user opens developer tools in Chrome browser and adds some other fields on the form or rename some existing fields ... so when submitted those fields will be bound back to the 'Person' bean and stored into database. Such way the user can spoof my form easily and chnage values for not allowed fields. Is there a way how to define (server side) which fields (bean properties) can be bound during the form submit?

Here is how the controller method signature looks like to get an idea:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/profile/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editProfile(@ModelAttribute("profile") Person doc, BindingResult result, Model m){
  ... saving doc to database ...
}
```

I'm using SpringBoot 1.3.5 with Thymeleaf ...

Comment: Create a method annotated with `@InitBinder` pass an argument of type [`WebDataBinder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/WebDataBinder.html) then you can configure which fields are allowed and/or disallowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that solution is quite simple. I just added `@InitBinder` annotated method to controller and used `WebDataBinder` provided object to specify list of fields allowed. To do this I can use `binder.setAllowedFields(...)` method. Field names support "xxx*", "*xxx" and "*xxx*" patterns so its easy to specify set of fields when named properly in the bean. Now when post request variables are bound to my bean, these allowed fields are preserved and the others are rejected and not bound.

Code example:

```
 @InitBinder // or @InitBinder("profile") with ModelAttribute name information
 public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
   binder.setAllowedFields("settings*");
 }
```

See [DataBinder docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html#setAllowedFields-java.lang.String...-) for detailed info.